# how to increase the row height of the header labels and font size of the row items in QTableWidget in pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

Here i want to increase the row height of the headerlabel and font size of the cell items. In my code I am using `self.table.setRowHeight()` method, but its not working. So please tell me is their any method to increase the row height of the header labels and font size of  cell items.

given bellow is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


ROUNDED_STYLE_SHEET1 = """QPushButton {
     background-color: green;
     color: white;
     border-style: outset;
     border-width: 4px;
     border-radius: 15px;
     border-color: none;
     font: bold 12px;
     min-width: 10em;
     padding: 10px;
 }
"""

OVAL = """QPushButton {

      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 20px 0;
      background: blue;
      border-radius: 48% / 25%;
      color: white;
      font: bold 10px;
}
"""

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
      self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Invoice Serial Number-39",self)
      self.label.setStyleSheet("font: bold 20pt AGENTORANGE")
      self.label.move(10,20)


      self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
      self.line_edit.move(900,15)
      self.line_edit.resize(300,30)
      self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("connect",self)
      self.btn1.setStyleSheet(ROUNDED_STYLE_SHEET1)
      self.btn1.move(1200,10)
      self.btn2 =QtGui.QPushButton("back", self)
      self.btn2.move(70,200)
      self.btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton("Reset Form", self)
      self.btn3.move(140,200)
      self.btn3.setStyleSheet("background-color:brown")
      self.btn4 = QtGui.QPushButton("pay", self) 
      self.btn4.setStyleSheet(OVAL)
      self.btn4.move(1200,170)

      self. table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
      self.table.move(10,70)
      self.table.resize(1350,100)
      self.table_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
      self.table.setRowCount(1)
      self.table.setColumnCount(6)
      self.tbutton = QtGui.QToolButton()
      self.tbutton.setToolTip("delete")
      self.tbutton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("trash1.png"))
      self.tbutton.setCheckable(True) 
      self.qspinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
      self.qspinbox.setMinimum(1)
      self.qspinbox.setMaximum(50)
      self.qspinbox.setRange(1,50)
      self.qspinbox.setMinimum(1)

      self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("S.no, Item Description,Qty,Rate(Rs:),Subtotal,"",").split(','))
      self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(("1").split(','))

      self.table.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("1"))
      self.table.setItem(0,1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Acne-aid Wash Facial Cleansing"))
      self.table.setItem(0,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("1"))
      self.table.setItem(0,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("191.72"))
      self.table.setItem(0,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("191.72"))
      self.table.setItem(0,5,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(""))
      self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
      self.table.setCellWidget(0,5,self.tbutton)
      self.table.setCellWidget(0,2,self.qspinbox)
      self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { font-size:  18pt};")
      self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("::section {background-color : lightGray;font-size:10pt;}")
      self.table.setRowHeight(0,100)
      self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
      self.table.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{ width:100%; height: 100px; }")




      self.table.setColumnWidth(0,100)
      self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

      self.table.setColumnWidth(1,250)
      self.table.setColumnWidth(2,300)
      self.table.setColumnWidth(3,250)
      self.table.setColumnWidth(4,250)
      self.table.setColumnWidth(5,200)





      self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
      # self.dialog = Example1()


      self.setWindowTitle("business management")
      self.setGeometry(200,300,900,600)
      self.showMaximized()

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.dialog.showMaximized() 


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    ex.setStyleSheet("background-color:white") 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase the height of the horizontal header you must use `setFixedHeight()`, for example:

```
self.table.horizontalHeader().setFixedHeight(60)
```

If you want to increase the font of the cells you must set the `setFont()` method of the `QTableWidget`:

```
fnt = self.table.font()
fnt.setPointSize(40)
self.table.setFont(fnt)
```

Comment: thq so much sir.

Comment: can i ask one more thing.. here in my code i set rowCount is 1 means it came like this in given image, but i dont want 1 here because already in s.no column i mentioned 1 so don t need again one so pls tell me how to hide or remove that one